# Where to find default text for supported languages in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am creating an application, and I noticed that nowhere can i find text such as 'pin to start' to use for livetiles in my application (creating a secondary tile). I tried to send Microsoft's AppHub a support ticket, but I only received a response saying that I could not be helped with translations? I clearly stated the need to be standardized and uniform across my third party apps and default behavior, but this had no effect on the answer. My problem arises when I translate my applications using a resx translator tool and Bing for my translation service. Some words to not translate correctly, which is fine because I go back through to check and then attempt to do this manually, but phrases such as 'pin to start' which are so unique to the WP7 application list sometimes do not translate properly at all. I would like to be as close to Microsoft's default language translations as possible for supported display languages, but are there any resources which may help me out? Or am I left in the dust to try to figure these out myself?

Comment: This is a good question... I'm interested in the answer, and surprised at your response from MS, since uniformity is important, and since I have several localized apps.

Comment: I essentially asked if they could reference some material or anything of the like that would have information regarding the localized phrases for the currently supported languages, and explained my situation in detail. They said that the dev center was for account management issues only, and refered me to this link that I'm sure you've come across as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520(v=vs.92) . So essentially no help at all regarding my question. Have you come across this issue, and if so, what was your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a page [Microsoft Terminology Collection](http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Terminology.aspx)  where you can download sets of standard texts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no document that will show you the localized versions of the system strings. For that, you will have to dig through OS files, and that implies that you will have access to the WP OS image. You have to rely on your own translation skills or simply switch languages on the phone to check specific strings.

Comment: Yea, I was probably going to do switch through the languages on the emulator while I test some featuers of my app, although finding some of the characters to type may be a little annoying. By the way I've seen your blog and referenced it in the past, great job!